# Reducing the inputs in TextInput widget

Tags: shiny

I'm very new to RShiny and thus trying to create a dashboard where a form will be prepopulated based on clicking actionButtons. I have multiple fields in this form. I want to reduce the size of the inputs in the TextInput widget. I tried the following code:

div(style="height: 60px;",textInput("pt1",  label = div(style = "font-size:11px","Patient ID"),value="12499")),

But this isn't working. It would be great if you could suggest some way out to fit in these fields in the page. I was able to reduce the text labels, but the entries are taking so much space.

Answer (score 0):

You can have smaller text inputs by adding the class `input-sm`. Here is a way to do so:

```
smallInput <- function(tag) {
  tag$children[[2]] <- htmltools::tagAppendAttributes(tag$children[[2]], class = "input-sm")
  tag
}
```

and in your UI, do

```
smallInput(textInput("pt1", label = div(style = "font-size:11px","Patient ID"),value="12499"))
```